# Extending a product in a category

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors

Consider category $\mathbf{Top}$ of topological spaces and category $\mathbf{Fcd}$ of endofuncoids. (To answer my question all you need to know about $\mathbf{Fcd}$ is that $\mathbf{Top}$ is its full subcategory, if you want more details read [the draft of the second volume of my book](http://www.mathematics21.org/algebraic-general-topology.html).)

Someone has said me the following about the attempt to extend Tychonoff product from $\mathbf{Top}$ to $\mathbf{Fcd}$:

Let $i$ be the inclusion functor from $\mathbf{Top}$ to $\mathbf{Fcd}$.

If $i$ has left adjoint:
If $r$ is left adjoint to $i$, we have $\operatorname{Hom}(A, i(X\times Y)) = \operatorname{Hom}(r(A), X\times Y) = \operatorname{Hom}(r(A), X)\times \operatorname{Hom}(r(A), Y) = \operatorname{Hom}(A, i(X))\times \operatorname{Hom}(A, i(Y)).$

If also the left adjoint is full and faithful:
$\operatorname{Hom}(A, i(r(X)\times r(Y))) = \operatorname{Hom}(r(A), r(X)\times r(Y)) = \operatorname{Hom}(r(A), r(X))\times \operatorname{Hom}(r(A), r(Y)) = \operatorname{Hom}(A, X)\times \operatorname{Hom}(A, Y).$

I doubt the formula $\operatorname{Hom}(r(A), X\times Y) = \operatorname{Hom}(r(A), X)\times \operatorname{Hom}(r(A), Y)$. Isn't it requiring that $\mathbf{Top}$ is monoidal closed? I think it isn't.

Also I doubt the formula $\operatorname{Hom}(r(A), r(X)\times r(Y)) = \operatorname{Hom}(r(A), r(X))\times \operatorname{Hom}(r(A), r(Y))$, because it is yet unknown whether $\mathbf{Fcd}$ is monoidal closed.

I also don't understand why $\operatorname{Hom}(r(A), r(X))\times \operatorname{Hom}(r(A), r(Y)) = \operatorname{Hom}(A, X)\times \operatorname{Hom}(A, Y)$.

Was the guy who wrote these formulas wrong? Or is it my bad understanding of his formulas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. $\hom(r(A),X\times Y)\cong \hom(r(A),X)\times\hom(r(A),Y)$ follows from the very definition of $X\times Y$ and doesn't require anything else. 
   The same holds to the next question with $r(X)$ and $r(Y)$.
2. The left adjoint - that you called $r$ (I guess because it is the *reflection* functor) - was assumed to be full and faithful here, i.e. bijective on homsets. 
   (The equality was meant isomorphic (in $\bf{Set}$).)